# Xpages across multiple databases

Tags: xpages

we are just going to start with `XPages` and i have the following questions:

We have a system composed of several Notes databases. Now we all want to add a XPage, so that can be edited in the browser and the client. 
What is better now: 
A database with the `XPages` and programming and data are fetched from the other databases. 
All databases get the `XPages` and are addressed individually via a navigation.

For me, what is better for performance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best practice is to store all XPage design elements for each "application" in a single NSF. This *can* be the same container as some of the data, or it can be a separate NSF entirely. But what you should *definitely* avoid is storing XPage elements in separate NSFs just because the *data* happens to be stored in several NSFs.

Rather, within XPage applications, the data should always be considered philosophically separate from the user interface, *even if it **is** stored in the same NSF*. This philosophy makes it easier to design modern, intuitive user interfaces for applications without constraining these design decisions simply as a result of how the back end data is structured.

The ACL of each NSF is still honored, so if you have imposed different access levels for each database, the user will still only be able to access content to which they have access based on the ACL of the NSF that contains each record, regardless of the ACL of the NSF that contains the XPage design elements.

One rather specific performance consideration is that both the [application scope](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpages-scoped-variables.htm) and the session scope are unique to the NSF that contains the XPage element a user is currently accessing. As such, if your application consists of 6 databases, for example, and you split the XPage design elements across those databases, you will be unable to cache configuration settings, or other computationally expensive queries, across all of the applications. If, conversely, all of the XPage design elements are in a single NSF, you have a single application scope. Each portion of the user interface, therefore, can access information already cached by any other portion of the interface -- spanning not only different pages within the app, but spanning users as well: if data that is retrieved for one user should be the same data returned to all users, caching it for one caches it for all.

Similarly, since the user will have a different session scope within each NSF they access, any user preferences (or behavior) that is applicable in all areas of the app would be forgotten as the user navigates to a different NSF.

Storing different XPage elements in different NSFs just because that's where the data is removes these, and other, opportunities for performance and interface optimization. It might feel simpler for those new to this type of development to segregate the design, but ultimately the end user experience is bound to suffer, potentially in ways of which they'll be consciously aware. But usually they'll be confused and frustrated and unable to pinpoint exactly why.

In short, here's the ***best*** way to determine where each XPage should be: if an end user navigating from one XPage to another would *assume* that they're still in the same app, then both should be in the same NSF, regardless of the location of the data each XPage accesses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the way that I have favored too.